# EBNF grammar (ANTLR)

Tags: antlr, grammar, ebnf

I've got a problem with EBNF grammar in ANTLRWorks:

```
line 37:    
upper_lower_case
: LOWER_CASE 
| UPPER_CASE
;

line 42:
CLASSNAME 
:   UPPER_CASE (DIGITS | upper_lower_case )*
;

line 51:
UPPER_CASE 
:   'A'..'Z'
;

line 55:
LOWER_CASE 
:   'a'..'z'
;

line 60:
DIGITS  :   '0'..'9'
;
```

I want CLASSNAME to always start with the capital letter and than it can consists of digits, upper or lower case letters.

Error log:

```
[13:11:59] warning(200): classgenerator.g:43:42: 
Decision can match input such as "'0'..'9'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
[13:11:59] warning(200): classgenerator.g:43:42: 
Decision can match input such as "<EOT>" using multiple alternatives: 2, 3

As a result, alternative(s) 3 were disabled for that input
[13:11:59] error(201): classgenerator.g:43:42: The following alternatives can never be 
matched: 3

[13:11:59] error(208): classgenerator.g:60:1: The following token definitions can never 
be matched because prior tokens match the same input: UPPER_CASE,DIGITS
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hladeo

EDIT:

So I should use fragment keyword if it doesn't refers to the tokens? In this way using fragment keyword will be wrong?

```
tokens {
PUBLIC    = '+';
PRIVATE   = '-';
PROTECTED = '=';
}

fragment ACCESSOR
: PUBLIC
| PRIVATE
| PROTECTED
;
```

and another question.

```
OBJECTNAME  
:   UPPER_LOWER_CASE (UPPER_LOWER_CASE | DIGIT)*
;
```

OBJECTNAME should consists of at least one letter (upper or lower cased doesn't matter) and optionally of another letters or digits - what's wrong with that part of the code? When I try to type for example `variable` - it's okay, but when I start with capital letter `Variable` I'm getting an error:

```
line 1:15 mismatched input 'Variable' expecting OBJECTNAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lexer rule `CLASSNAME` currently references parser rule `upper_lower_case` (lexer rules start with an uppercase letter; parser rules start with lowercase). Lexer rules can only reference lexer rules.

In addition, it appears that `UPPER_CASE`, `LOWER_CASE`, and `DIGITS` should not create tokens themselves so they should be marked as `fragment` rules. In the following example, I changed `DIGITS` to `DIGIT` since it only ever matches one digit.

```
CLASSNAME : UPPER_CASE (DIGIT | UPPER_LOWER_CASE)*;

fragment UPPER_LOWER_CASE : LOWER_CASE | UPPER_CASE;
fragment UPPER_CASE : 'A'..'Z';
fragment LOWER_CASE : 'a'..'z';
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

**Edit 1 (for the edits in the question):**

- A piece of text in the input can only have one token type. For example, consider the input text `X3`. Since this text could match a `CLASSNAME` or an `OBJECTNAME`, the lexer will end up assigning it the type of the first rule appearing in the grammar. In other words, if `CLASSNAME` appears before `OBJECTNAME` in the grammar, the input `X3` will *always* be a `CLASSNAME` token and will *never* be a `OBJECTNAME` token. If `OBJECTNAME` appears before `CLASSNAME` in the grammar, the input `X3` will *always* be an `OBJECTNAME` and *never* be a `CLASSNAME` (in fact, in this case no token will ever be a `CLASSNAME`).
- Your `ACCESSOR` rule looks like it should be a parser rule, like the following:

  ```
  accessor : PUBLIC | PROTECTED | PRIVATE;
  ```

**Edit 2 (for the comment about distinguishing `CLASSNAME` and `OBJECTNAME`):**

To distinguish between `CLASSNAME` and `OBJECTNAME`, you can create a lexer rule `IDENTIFIER` which matches either.

```
IDENTIFIER : UPPER_LOWER_CASE (DIGIT | UPPER_LOWER_CASE)*;
```

You can then create a parser rule to handle the distinction:

```
classname : IDENTIFIER;
objectname : IDENTIFIER;
```

Obviously this allows `x3` to be a `classname`, which is not valid in your language. When possible, I always prefer to relax the parser rules a bit and perform further validation later where I can provide a better error message. For example, if you allow `x3` to match `classname`, then after you parse the input and have an AST (ANTLR 3) or parse tree (ANTLR 4), you can look for all instances of `classname` and make sure that the matched `IDENTIFIER` starts with the required upper case letter.

Example error message produced by the parser's automatic error reporting:

> line 1:15 mismatched input 'variable' expecting CLASSNAME

Example error message produced by separate validation:

> line 1:15 class name `variable` must start with an upper case letter

Comment: So is there any possibility to distinguish CLASSNAME and OBJECTNAME? I'm writing simple Java class generator where I could type: `create ClassName +name:String, -age:int;` where variable, age, String and int are OBJECTNAMEs.

Comment: I'm little dissappointed that it can't be done on the parser stage. Anyway thank you very much for help :)

Comment: @Hladeo to the contrary, I actually *recommend* moving it to the parser stage (with the parser rules `classname` and `objectname`). To do so, you just have to make sure the lexer isn't trying to separate the two.